Is there a way to get better image rendering performance in Chrome when scrolling?
I have a container set to display image thumbnails with a css grid. There are about 5000 image elements and if I scroll too fast, Chrome can't seem to manage to display them quickly enough and it looks like I am scrolling an empty container until I stop and give it a frame or two to catch up. Is there anything I can do to improve the performance? I can get smooth, frame perfect scrolling of 5000 thumbnails if I resort to canvas using ImageBitmap instead of HTMLImageElement, but this adds a lot of extra implementation (not to mention memory usage.)

I assume it takes a while for the client to download 5000 images from the server.  Is this loading process complete when you start scrolling?

@James Yes, It's coming from localhost over HTTP/2, so it only takes a couple seconds to load everything. This is purely a rendering issue.

Yes.. there is a way to get better image rendering performance in chrome when scrolling by using WebP format rather then JPEG and PNG..

I am already using WebP.
